# TFS screen layout

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am trying to change my view of TFS item, but not the entire groups view of it.
Spent a little time googling and searching stack, but I didn't see references that allow me to make changes at a personal level, only at a global level.

I have been using VSS for the last 10 years and this is my first time using TFS, so I may use terms wrong or not know something.

- I am using VS2012 connected to TFS 2013
- I am using a 24in monitor in portrait

So when looking at a work item I see roughly:

- Top: vertical 25% @ 100% wide containing work item properties boxes.
- Bottom: vertical 75% containing 2 panels/sections @ 50% wide each.

  - Panel 1 containing tabs: details, all items, attachments.
  - Panel 2 containing tab: history.

In portrait this sucks and scrunches the details to a small column, that inconsistently uses word wrapping.

Ideally I would like to move the history panel into the other group so that I have only 1 section/panel.

Sans that, being able to at least re-size the 50/50 split as needed so I could see more of any given section.

No where on the screen or menus can I find a way to re-size or move these panels/sections.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If you can use the web interface and have applied the latest updates to the server, there are nice little "expander" buttons in the larger text fields to allow you to view more of the text areas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The work item screen cannot be customized on a personal level, only at the Team project level and applies to all users of that Team Project. Microsoft is introducing a much better (in my opinion) work item screen in TFS 2015 update 1, which works better on smaller screens and portrait display.